# auto rig pro ; Blender to Unreal (Bones hierarchy problem)

Tags: unreal-engine, auto-rig-pro

i'm using autorigpro to create a long neck head. So i'm using spline ik as the neck, connect to head bones.
While in blender, the head is parented to spline ,as the head correctly follows where the neck moves, but the problem comes up when i export to unreal.

When i export to Unreal, the head bones won't go join/under the spline hierarchy. Does anyone knows how to properly make the spline ik and head bones under same hierarchy?

Below is the example picture of blender's rig on the left, and the unreal bones hierarchy on the right. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. Just simple script typing.

1.Open text editor and i typed

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
neck = bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones.get('neck.x')
c_spline_04 = bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones.get('c_spline_04.x')
neck.parent = c_spline_04
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
```

Bone names in the script is relative to name bones in your rig.

2.Next, to force the neck parent export, save the script as postscript.py then set the file path in "Custom Export Script"(inside Auto rig pro menu) and export. it should be fixed.

[image]